# I can't add the @IsNotEmpty() validator in nestjs Dtos

Tags: javascript, validation, exception, nestjs, dto

[image]

I can't add the @IsNotEmpty() validator in nestjs Dtos

Comment: Your dto need to be a class to use it

Answer (score 1):

Decorators in Typescript can only apply to classes, class members, class methods, and class method parameters. This is an interface, so it's not a valid location for a decorator.